# BCD Hex String to Integer

Tags: c#, .net, numbers, bcd

I was able to modify the solution provided by Brad Christie to get the results I am expecting for the Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Months, Days, and Years all of which are in BCD Format:

```
static Int32 GetYearFromBCD(Int32 time) 
{ 
int length = time.ToString().Length -1;
List<Int32> YearList = new List<Int32>(); 
for (Int32 i = length; i >= 0; i --) 
{ 
Int32 place = i * 4; 
Int32 val = 0x01 << place; 

Int32 curVal = (Int32)(time / val); 
if (curVal > 9 && YearList.Count > 0) 
{ 
Int32 delta = (Int32)(curVal / 10); 
YearList[YearList.Count - 1] += delta; 
curVal -= delta * 10; 
} 
YearList.Add(curVal); 
time -= curVal << place; 
} 
Int32 Year = 0; 
for (Int32 y = 0; y < YearList.Count; y++) 
Year += YearList[y] * (Int32)Math.Pow(10,(length+1 - y)-1); 
return Year; 
}
```

I wanted to provide an update to this question.  After the device was running for several days through New Years, I was able to full confirm that the code solution Brad posted does exactly what we will need.

I was able to confirm my suspicions that the expected value was indeed a Binary Coded Decmial, I was able to confirm that the value expected only works has a HEX value.  A co-worker was able to independently confirm the time and date, using table for the standard, so I feel comfortable putting this to bed.

I was able to confirm that for whatever reason the decmial value of the data does not work, I can only conclude the data is being sent as a hex value by the device, my only concern is will other applications work in a similar method.

I appreciate everyone's help in figuring this out, some of the comments lead me down a path that allow me to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Well, even though the numbers don't seem to make sense, this is what I came up with (giving the results *you're* expecting (from the examples provided). Take this through the wringer and see if it comes out with all the results you are expecting:

```
static Int32 GetYearFromBCD(Int32 time)
{
    List<Int32> YearList = new List<Int32>();
    for (Int32 i = 3; i >= 0; i --)
    {
        Int32 place = i * 4;
        Int32 val = 0x01 << place;

        Int32 curVal = (Int32)(time / val);
        if (curVal > 9 && YearList.Count > 0)
        {
            Int32 delta = (Int32)(curVal / 10);
            YearList[YearList.Count - 1] += delta;
            curVal -= delta * 10;
        }
        YearList.Add(curVal);
        time -= curVal << place;
    }
    Int32 Year = 0;
    for (Int32 y = 0; y < 4; y++)
        Year += YearList[y] * (Int32)Math.Pow(10,(4 - y)-1);
    return Year;
}
```

I'm really just taking a shot in the dark at this as the numbers you gave aren't what I would call typical. Having said that, you have to make what you're receiving work, so :shrug:.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert number to hex representation just use ToString with "x" as param:

```
2010.ToString("x")  output: "7da"
```

However, I don't really understand what to you want to achieve if you say that for 2010, you expect 200A.

Comment: It's also not `0x200A` in BCD, it's `0x2010`.

Comment: Then your documentation is lying. As we've all been saying, BCD for 2010 is `0x2010`. Either your documentation is mistaken as to the format of the dates, or there is a bug in the implementation that produces non-BCD values.

Comment: The mistake is pretty obvious. They take `0x2000` as a base and add the century year to it. That works for `0x2000` through `0x2009` but fails on `0x2010`, giving you `0x200A` instead.

Comment: Hey, you're the one defending incorrect documentation. I'm just offering a possible explanation for the discrepancy. ;)

Comment: I again refer you to my previous assertion: "your documentation, stating that the data is in BCD format, is incorrect."

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure that your example is correct? Why do you have a hex-number, where the first part is with base 10 and the second part is base 16?

*Normal* would one of these:

- 2010 => 0x07DA

  - complete hex
- 2010 => 0x140A

  - the number is broken half-way and each part is hex
- 2010 => 0x2010

  - bcd encoded as found on wikipedia (where else) ;-)

After some googling and thinking here is my first idea:

- Put everything into an [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx).
- Get all values individually out of it by calling [BinaryReader.ReadByte()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbyte.aspx) and cast it to an int
- Multiply each value first by 10, then divide by 16
- Put all of this individual values into a `List<int>`
- use `Math.Pow(value, 10 * (List.Count - indexOfValue))` to aggregate all these values